# What makes table lookups so cheap?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, big-o, lookup

A while back, I learned a little bit about big O notation and the efficiency of different algorithms.

For example, looping through each item in an array to do something with it

```
foreach(item in array)
    doSomethingWith(item)
```

is an `O(n)` algorithm, because the number of cycles the program performs is directly proportional to the size of the array.

What amazed me, though, was that table lookup is `O(1)`. That is, looking up a key in a hash table or dictionary

```
value = hashTable[key]
```

takes the same number of cycles regardless of whether the table has one key, ten keys, a hundred keys, or a gigabrajillion keys.

This is really cool, and I'm very happy that it's true, but it's unintuitive to me and I don't understand *why* it's true.

I can understand the first `O(n)` algorithm, because I can compare it to a real-life example: if I have sheets of paper that I want to stamp, I can go through each paper one-by-one and stamp each one. It makes a lot of sense to me that if I have 2,000 sheets of paper, it will take twice as long to stamp using this method than it would if I had 1,000 sheets of paper.

But I can't understand why table lookup is `O(1)`. I'm thinking that if I have a dictionary, and I want to find the definition of *polymorphism*, it will take me `O(logn)` time to find it: I'll open some page in the dictionary and see if it's alphabetically before or after *polymorphism*. If, say, it was after the *P* section, I can eliminate all the contents of the dictionary after the page I opened and repeat the process with the remainder of the dictionary until I find the word *polymorphism*.

This is not an `O(1)` process: it will usually take me longer to find words in a thousand page dictionary than in a two page dictionary. I'm having a hard time imagining a process that takes the same amount of time regardless of the size of the dictionary.

**tl;dr**: Can you explain to me how it's possible to do a table lookup with `O(1)` complexity?

(If you show me how to replicate the amazing `O(1)` lookup algorithm, I'm definitely going to get a big fat dictionary so I can show off to all of my friends my ninja-dictionary-looking-up skills)

**EDIT:** Most of the answers seem to be contingent on this assumption:

> You have the ability to access any page of a dictionary given its page number in constant time

If this is true, it's easy for me to see. But I don't know why this underlying assumption is true: I would use the same process to to look up a page by number as I would by word.

Same thing with memory addresses, what algorithm is used to load a memory address? What makes it so cheap to find a piece of memory from an address? In other words, why is memory access `O(1)`?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article on hash-tables?  Does that explain what you need to know?

Comment: It's all very well described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @Oli Not really, it mostly talks about collisions and hashing methods and stuff like that.

Comment: @Peter: And that's precisely what you need to know to understand how a hash table works!  And even if you don't want to read it all, there are diagrams that illustrate the concept.

Comment: Re your edit: Do you know arrays and how they work? If you don't, trying to understand hash tables is futile, as they use arrays under the hood.

Comment: What makes it so cheap to find a piece of memory by its address is that there is a constant upper bound on the number of "pieces of memory" as determined by the pointer size. Even if looking up a piece of memory by its address takes O(pointer size), that would still be constant time because the pointer size is constant.

Comment: @harold I think that addresses my question better than most of the answers here. If you posted it in an answer, I would probably accept it.

Comment: To be fair, your question mostly asks about hash tables, which is why all the answers talk about hash tables! If you wanted to know about arrays (or memory), you probably should have asked about them originally...

Comment: @Oli I guess I wasn't very clear about it, but I really just wanted to know how lookup could be `O(1)`. I didn't really care if it was a hash table, a dictionary, an array, or a memory address. I just wanted to know about lookup algorithms.

Comment: @Peter: Ok, fair enough.  Anyway, I've expanded on this final point in a further update to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

But the essence is that you first apply a hash function to your key, which converts it to an integer index (this is `O(1)`).  This is then used to index into an array, which is also `O(1)`.  If the hash function has been well designed, there should only be one (or a few items) stored at each location in the array, so the lookup is complete.

So in massively-simplified pseudocode:

```
ValueType array[ARRAY_SIZE];

void insert(KeyType k, ValueType v)
{
    int index = hash(k);
    array[index] = v;
}

ValueType lookup(KeyType k)
{
    int index = hash(k);
    return array[index];
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't handle collisions, but you can read the article to learn how that's handled.

**Update**

To address the edited question, indexing into an array is *O(1)* because underneath the hood, the CPU is doing this:

```
    ADD index, array_base_address -> pointer
    LOAD pointer -> some_cpu_register
```

where `LOAD` loads data stored in memory at the specified address.

**Update 2**

And the reason a load from memory is `O(1)` is really just because this is an axiom we usually specify when we talk about computational complexity (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_model).  If we ignore cache hierarchies and data-access patterns, then this is a reasonable assumption.  As we scale the size of the machine,, this may not be true (a machine with 100TB of storage may not take the same amount of time as a machine with 100kB).  But usually, we assume that the storage capacity of our machine is constant, and much much bigger than any problem size we're likely to look at.  So for all intents and purposes, it's a constant-time operation.

Comment: I'm not completely sure I follow. An index is just a special type of key, why does it suddenly make it *O(1)* to do a lookup with an index? (BTW, not my downvote)

Comment: @Peter: Are you comfortable with the concept that if you have an array e.g. `T my_array[100000];`, then it's an `O(1)` operation to access e.g. `my_array[53]`?

Comment: It's basically the same concept to me: it's like finding the 53rd page of a book.

Comment: @Peter: Consider that in order to obtain the value at `my_array[53]`, all the compiler has to do is take the base address of the array, add 53 to it, and load the value from memory at that computed address.

Comment: @peter, an index is not a special type of key in an array. It is an offset into the array for direct access of a single element. An index in a database is different.

Comment: @Peter: See my updated question, which addresses your updated question.

Comment: @Oli Ok. It still begs the question, though, how does it find the address? I don't understand why that's any faster than looking up an index.

Comment: @Peter Olson: start_address + (sizeof(ElementType) * 53) is constant time.

Comment: Peter: every page in the book has a label with the page number sticking out. Just grabbing the label and using it to open the book, gets to the correct page.

Comment: By the way, extending this metaphor, even if you label only odd-numbered pages you can get every page in O(1). And the same if you label only 1 every 10 pages. As long as the size of the grouping is not dependent on the total number of pages, the "get a label [hash code], then scan a fixed-sized set of pages with the same label" procedure is O(1).

Comment: @Erik Burigo: but searching which label to pick is still an O(log n) process, especially once you get too many labels sticking out from your book.

Comment: @Lie: Doing it by eye is a bad analogy.  A better analogy would be using a ruler to measure a certain depth of pages.

Comment: @Lie, Oli: A better analogy would be that you can just go to a page number because you have direct addressing. The analogy breaks down because of the physical limitations of human vision and cognition. If a computer has a phsyical address it doesn't *need* to search through the rest of the addresses to find the one it's looking for, it puts the bits on the bus and it's done.

Comment: @Dave Newton: unfortunately, there is no such thing as "direct addressing", even a RAM still need to do binary search to address a particular memory cell. Granted they do this in hardware, and the time complexity of the binary search depends on the length of the memory address. My answer below describes how this process is done in the RAM, and why for most programmers it's often convenient to treat memory addressing as O(1), although it's actually not.

Comment: No such thing as "direct addressing"?! Um. Take a processor with a 16-bit memory bus. Put 16-bits of address on the bus. Strobe a R/W pin. There's no "binary search" with a muxed address bus either: put addr1 on the bus, latch it. Addr2, strobe R/W, value is on the data bus. I have no idea what you're referring to. A binary search is a specific thing: there is nothing like that happening on a non-muxed bus, and very little like it happening on a muxed bus.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Look deeper. After you put the address on the bus and strobe the R/W pin, the RAM still have to locate the capacitors that corresponds to this address. Guess how the RAM locate the capacitors? Hint: not by a magic technique called "direct addressing". Muxed/non-muxed bus have nothing to do with any of these. `A binary search is a specific thing`; false, binary search (or almost any named algorithms) refers to a class of algorithms with a shared basic idea, it has hundreds of variants, including hardware implementations.

Comment: Yeah, your argument is that a grid of wires is a binary search. That's being pretty pedantic, IMO, but whatever.

Comment: (And I still disagree that a binary search is anything other than cutting stuff in half, that's why it's called "binary"--that isn't what a memory grid does. A binary search is a specific type of generic divide-and-conquer, but it's not dichotomic, because there are more than two choices.)

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Suppose one needs to energize one of 65,536 rows using based upon a particular 16-bit memory address.  One could use a 16-input AND gate, or five 4-input "AND" gates (the first four check four bits each; the last one checks the outputs of the first four), or fifteen 2-input "AND" gates.  Depending upon what one assumes about the relative propagation speeds of gates with various numbers of input, any of those approaches could be fastest, but none of them requires time proportional to the number of address bits.

Comment: @supercat: compare the amount of time needed to check 16-bit memory address to 24-bit memory address, you'll need either a 24-input AND gate, or 23 2-input AND gates. As the number of address bits increases, the number of transistors increases, and therefore lookup time also increases compared to 16-bit address size. Fortunately, in a DRAM (one found on regular RAM), this is comparatively very small compared to charging/discharging of capacitors; in SRAM (one found on CPU caches) the size of addresses affects lookup time more significantly, which is why bigger caches may not always be better.

Answer (score 7):

I'll address the question from a different perspective from every one else. Hopefully this will give light to why the accessing `x[45]` and accessing `x[5454563]` takes the same amount of time.

A RAM is laid out in a grid (i.e. rows and columns) of capacitors. A RAM can address a particular cell of memory by activating a particular column and row on the grid, so let's say if you have a 16-byte capacity RAM, laid out in a 4x4 grid (insanely small for modern computer, but sufficient for illustrative purpose), and you're trying to access the memory address 13 (`1101`), you first split the address into rows and column, i.e `row 3 (11) column 1 (01)`.

Let's suppose a 0 means taking the left intersection and a 1 means taking a right intersection. So when you want to activate row 3, you send an army of electrons in the row starting gate, the row-army electrons went right, right to reach row 3 activation gate; next you send another army of electrons on the column starting gate, the column-army electrons went left then right to reach the 1st column activation gate. A memory cell can only be read/written if the row and column are both activated, so this would allow the marked cell to be read/written.

[image: RAM Grid]

The effect of all this gibberish is that the **access time of a memory address depends on the address length**, and not the particular memory address itself; if an architecture uses a 32-bit address space (i.e. 32 intersections), then addressing memory address 45 and addressing memory address 5454563 both will still have to pass through all 32 intersections (actually 16 intersections for the row electrons and 16 intersections for the columns electrons).

Note that in reality memory addressing takes very little amount of time compared to charging and discharging the capacitors, therefore even if we start having a 512-bit length address space (enough for ~1.4*10^130 yottabyte of RAM, i.e. enough to keep everything under the sun in your RAM), which mean the electrons would have to go through 512 intersections, it wouldn't really add that much time to the actual memory access time.

Note that this is a gross oversimplification of modern RAM. In modern DRAM, if you want to access subsequent memory addresses you only change the columns and not spend time changing the rows, therefore accessing subsequent memory is much faster than accessing totally random addresses. Also, this description is totally ignorant about the effect of CPU cache (although CPU cache also uses a similar grid addressing scheme, however since CPU cache uses the much faster transistor-based capacitor, the negative effect of having large cache address space becomes very critical). However, the point still holds that if you're jumping around the memory, accessing any one of them will take the same amount of time.

Comment: +1 Excellent, well thought-out answer. I know very little about hardware, but this explains things well.

Comment: @Peter Olson: so I guess the next challenge is how to redesign the physical dictionary so that we can do an O(1) lookup instead of the usual O(log n) in a normal dictionary.

Comment: Yes, I was a little bit disappointed how nobody really said anything about that. :)

Comment: @Peter Olson: I've had a few ideas, but I don't think linguists would be too happy to have to solve a few math equations before they can start looking for words :-). I'd rather buy a decent electronic dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, it's surprisingly difficult to find a real-world example of this. The idea of course is that you're looking for something by address and not value.

The dictionary example fails because you don't immediately know the location of page say 278. You still have to look that up the same as you would a word because the page locations are not in your memory.

But say I marked a number on each of your fingers and then I told you to wiggle the one with 15 written on it. You'd have to look at each of them (assuming its unsorted), and if it's not 15 you check the next one. O(n).

If I told you to wiggle your right pinky. You don't have to look anything up. You know where it is because I just told you where it is. The value I just passed to you is its address in your "memory."

It's kind of like that with databases, but on a much larger scale than just 10 fingers.

Answer (score 1):

Because work is done up front -- the value is put in a bucket that is easily accessible given the hashcode of the key.  It would be like if you wanted to look up your work in the dictionary but had marked the exact page the word was on.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had a dictionary where everything starting with letter A was on page 1, letter B on page 2...etc. So if you wanted to look up "balloon" you would know exactly what page to go to. This is the concept behind O(1) lookups.

Arbitrary data input => maps to a specific memory address

The trade-off of course being you need more memory to allocate for all the potential addresses, many of which may never be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with 999999999 locations, how long does it take to find a record by social security number?

Assuming you don't have that much memory, then allocate about 30% more array locations that the number of records you intend to store, and then write a hash function to look it up instead.

A very simple (and probably bad) hash function would be social % numElementsInArray.

The problem is collisions--you can't guarantee that every location holds only one element. But thats ok, instead of storing the record at the array location, you can store a linked list of records. Then you scan linearly for the element you want once you hash to get the right array location.

Worst case this is O(n)--everything goes to the same bucket. Average case is O(1) because in general if you allocate enough buckets and your hash function is good, records generally don't collide very often.

Comment: `social % numElementsInArray` is actually a decent hash function (except of course that it requires you to know the elements beforehand; it's also likely you can just replace it by the identity function), as long as the hashtable implementation is as cleverly as the better real-world implementations (from studying CPython's, I can assure you that collisions are only an issue in that example if the lower `ceil (log_2 numElementsInArray)` bits are shared by several social security numbers).

Comment: I believe my textbook says that social % numElementsInArray is ok as long as numElementsInArray is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, hash-tables in a nutshell:

You take a regular array (O(1) access), and instead of using regular Int values to access it, you use MATH.

What you do, is to take the key value (lets say a string) calculate it into a number (some function on the characters) and then use a well known mathematical formula that gives you a relatively good distribution on the array's range.

So, in that case you are just doing like 4-5 calculations (O(1)) to get an object from that array, using a key which isn't an int.

Now, avoiding collisions, and finding the right mathematical formula for good distribution is the hard part. That's what is explained pretty well in wikipedia: [**en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup tables know exactly how to access the given item in the table **before hand**. 
Completely the opposite of say, finding an item by it's value in a sorted array, where you have to access items to check that it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a hashtable is a series of buckets (addresses in memory) and a function that maps objects from a domain into those buckets.

Say your domain is 3 letter words, you'd block out 26^3=17,576 addresses for all the possible 3 letter words and create a function that maps all 3 letter words to those addresses, e.g., aaa=0, aab=1, etc. Now when you have a word you'd like to look up, say, "and", you know immediately from your O(1) function that it is address number 367.